# RSpec reads context first, then reads before(:all). Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, rspec

My environment:

```
jruby-1.5.3
Rails 2.3.8
RSpec 1.3.1
Windows 7 (64-bit machine)
```

Running Rspec with the following source code, why does rspec read line marked with '=>' which is context before the statement `before(:each)`. Any help much appreciated

```
def save_env
  @host_os = Config::CONFIG['host_os']
end

def restore_env
  Config::CONFIG['host_os'] = @host_os
end

describe Manager::ManagerConfig do
  before(:each) do
    save_env
  end

  after(:each) do
    restore_env
  end

  context "Within Linus/Solaris environment" do
=>  Config::CONFIG['host_os'] = 'linux'

    it "should return the correct manager path under linux/solaris" do
      # bar
    end

    it "should return the correct license path under windows env" do
      # foo
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

A context sets up an inner class, so the lines within it are going to be executed at load time, except that each `it`, `before` and `after` creates a block of code that will be executed later.

All you need to do is wrap the config setup in its own `before(:each)` block, and the order will be what you expect: The outer `before(:each)`, then the inner `before(:each)`, then the `it`:

```
before(:each) do
  Config::CONFIG['host_os'] = 'linux'
end
```